# Generating two sequences with one function and one parameter

Tags: r, sequence, seq, rep

I want to generate these two sequences:

```
A = c(0.25,0.50,0.75,1,0.25,0.50,0.75,0.25,0.50,0.25)
B = c(0.33,0.66,1,0.33,0.66,0.33)
```

with one function.
I already have this:

```
X = 5
X = 4
rep(seq(1/(X-1),1,1/(X-1)), X-1)
```

but, I still need to remove some values,
I did it like this, but that is not really the right way:

```
rep(seq(1/(X-1),1,1/(X-1)), X-1)[-c(8,11,12,14,15,16)]
rep(seq(1/(X-1),1,1/(X-1)), X-1)[-c(6,8,9)]
```

Is there a way to write this in a single function?

Comment: `f = function(x) sequence(x:1)/x;  f(4); f(3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is by `sequence(x:1)/x`, with `x` taking the required value.

```
> f = function(x) sequence(x:1)/x
> f(4)
# [1] 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 0.25 0.50 0.25
> f(3)
# [1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

(This is assuming that `sequence` counts as one function i.e. and we don't include `:` and `/` etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The `sequence` approach by [@user20650](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525997/12158757) is a super elegant option already. Below is another one but not that concise

```
f <- function(x) unlist(sapply(x:1, seq)) / x
```

such that

```
> f(3)
[1] 0.3333333 0.6666667 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333
> f(4)
 [1] 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00 0.25 0.50 0.75 0.25 0.50 0.25
```

Comment: It concise enough ... in fact it is almost exactly how sequence used to be written before it was rewritten in C in v4.0